# Error: /tmp/ccOB6cIT.o: In function `main': example.c:(.text+0x4a)

Tags: compiling, gcc, c

I picked up the following code from a practice file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *kidfunc(void *p) 
{
printf ("Kid ID is ---> %d\n", getpid( ));
}
int main(int count, char* argv[])
{
pthread_t kid ;
pthread_create (&kid, NULL, kidfunc, NULL) ;
printf ("Parent ID is ---> %d\n", getpid( )) ;
pthread_join (kid, NULL) ;
printf ("No more kid!\n") ;
return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it on my laptop (running Ubuntu 14.04) it generates the following error:

```
ahsan-15f8116@VirtualWorld:~$ gcc example.c
/tmp/ccOB6cIT.o: In function `main':
example.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
example.c:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This doesn't make any sense to me, because the header includes `pthread.h`, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headers only *declare* functions, it is **libraries** that *define* them.

Usually you would need to add libraries to be linked explicitly on the `gcc` command line e.g. `gcc -o prog prog.c -lm` for the math library `libm`. However the `pthread` library is a special case - it is linked by a special compiler flag `-pthread`:

```
gcc -pthread example.c
```

From `man gcc`

```
-pthread
    Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This
    option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple ... use libpthread.so :

```
$ gcc -o EXAMPLE -lpthread example.c

$ ./EXAMPLE
Parent ID is ---> 9280          
Kid ID is ---> 9280             
No more kid!
```